# Firebase Authentication suddenly stopped working

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-authentication

I have an android app that does not require a log in, but I do have Anonymous sign-in enabled so that I can retrieve the userID from Firebase and use it to log specific events. I have the feeling that it just stopped retrieving the UID from Firebase.

What I've done to resolve the issue is the following:

- updated all the dependencies
- updated the emulator
- Installed a new emulator
- re-added the google services plugin
- re-added google-services.json file
- updated Android Manifest
- I've tried to create a login-activity for the sake of testing, where through a button with an onclicklisterer, the user get's anoynmously logged in.
- I've doubled checked Local History in Android Studio to see whether big changes were made to the code, not the case. [See screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u5L4q.png)
- Enabled and disabled anonymous login from the Firebase Console.
- Re-written the entire code based on [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/anonymous-auth) from Firebase.
- I've basically tried every solution there is

My Manifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="com.superawesome.metime">


    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/wazzup"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".Cardview" />
        <activity android:name=".cardviewactivity" />


        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.APPLICATION_ID"
            android:value="ca-app-pub-xxx" />

        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity
            android:name="com.google.firebase.auth.internal.FederatedSignInActivity"
            tools:replace="android:launchMode"
            android:launchMode="standard" />

        <service
            android:name=".MyFirebaseInstanceIDService">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.firebase.INSTANCE_ID_EVENT"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </service>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

My code:

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case android.R.id.home:
            NavUtils.navigateUpFromSameTask(this);
            return true; // go back to the first screen

        case R.id.cardoverview:
            startActivity(new Intent(this, cardviewactivity.class));
            return true; //go to the screen where all the swiped right activities are stored


    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    mAuth.addAuthStateListener(mAuthListener);
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getInstanceId()
            .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<InstanceIdResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<InstanceIdResult> task) {
                    if (!task.isSuccessful()) {
                        Log.w("This Tag", "getInstanceId failed", task.getException());
                        return;
                    } else {
                        Log.d("This tag", "We need this");
                    }
                }
            });

    swipeDb = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users");
    final FirebaseFirestore db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();


    //Anonymous user login to be registered in Firebase
    mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    mCurrentUser = mAuth.getCurrentUser(); // save the UID of the user in users in Firebase without having to log in

    final String UID = mCurrentUser.getUid();
    DatabaseReference currentUserDb = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users").child("UID");
    currentUserDb.setValue(UID); //save the User UID to the Firebase Realtime database



    // Calling to the AdMob API to add advertisements to the banner in the main view.Gotta make that dough
    // Change this to big cards in the future
    final AdView adView = findViewById(R.id.adView);

    final AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder()
            //.addTestDevice(AdRequest.DEVICE_ID_EMULATOR)
            .build();
```

[Screenshot to Firebase Authentication](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jbfI8.png)

Error I'm receiving from the logcat:

```
W/DynamiteModule: Local module descriptor class for com.google.firebase.auth not found.
I/FirebaseCrashlytics: Initializing Crashlytics 17.0.0
I/FirebaseInitProvider: FirebaseApp initialization successful
I/FirebaseAuth: [FirebaseAuth:] Preparing to create service connection to gms implementation
D/libEGL: loaded /vendor/lib/egl/libEGL_emulation.so
D/libEGL: loaded /vendor/lib/egl/libGLESv1_CM_emulation.so
D/libEGL: loaded /vendor/lib/egl/libGLESv2_emulation.so
V/FA: onActivityCreated
W/rawesome.metim: Accessing hidden method Landroid/view/View;->computeFitSystemWindows(Landroid/graphics/Rect;Landroid/graphics/Rect;)Z (greylist, reflection, allowed)
    Accessing hidden method Landroid/view/ViewGroup;->makeOptionalFitsSystemWindows()V (greylist, reflection, allowed)
V/FA: App measurement disabled via the init parameters
I/FA: App measurement initialized, version: 28000
    To enable debug logging run: adb shell setprop log.tag.FA VERBOSE
    To enable faster debug mode event logging run:
      adb shell setprop debug.firebase.analytics.app com.superawesome.metime
D/FA: Debug-level message logging enabled
V/FA: Detected application was in foreground
D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.superawesome.metime, PID: 21746
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.superawesome.metime/com.superawesome.metime.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseUser.getUid()' on a null object reference
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3341)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3485)
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:83)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2045)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7478)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:549)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:941)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseUser.getUid()' on a null object reference
        at com.superawesome.metime.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:118)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7989)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7978)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1309)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3316)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3485) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:83) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2045) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7478) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:549) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:941) 
V/FA: Connecting to remote service
D/FA: Event not sent since app measurement is disabled

com.superawesome.metime.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:118) --> final String UID = mCurrentUser.getUid();
```

I've been trying to resolve this issue for over a week now with no success

Edit:

I know I can add listeners to see if the user is anonymously signed in or not. The whole problem around this is that the user is not being signed in anymore at all.

Edit2:

From logcat:

```
2020-05-30 12:39:53.655 23257-23297/com.superawesome.metime I/DynamiteModule: Selected remote version of com.google.android.gms.ads.dynamite, version >= 21600
2020-05-30 12:39:53.658 23257-23297/com.superawesome.metime V/DynamiteModule: Dynamite loader version >= 2, using loadModule2NoCrashUtils
2020-05-30 12:39:53.770 23257-23311/com.superawesome.metime I/TetheringManager: registerTetheringEventCallback:com.superawesome.metime
2020-05-30 12:39:53.818 23257-23303/com.superawesome.metime W/DynamiteModule: Local module descriptor class for com.google.firebase.auth not found.
2020-05-30 12:39:54.025 23257-23303/com.superawesome.metime I/FirebaseAuth: [FirebaseAuth:] Preparing to create service connection to gms implementation
2020-05-30 12:39:54.076 23257-23257/com.superawesome.metime I/FirebaseCrashlytics: Initializing Crashlytics 17.0.0
2020-05-30 12:39:54.220 23257-23257/com.superawesome.metime I/FirebaseInitProvider: FirebaseApp initialization successful
2020-05-30 12:39:54.332 23257-23332/com.superawesome.metime D/libEGL: loaded /vendor/lib/egl/libEGL_emulation.so
2020-05-30 12:39:54.342 23257-23332/com.superawesome.metime D/libEGL: loaded /vendor/lib/egl/libGLESv1_CM_emulation.so
2020-05-30 12:39:54.362 23257-23332/com.superawesome.metime D/libEGL: loaded /vendor/lib/egl/libGLESv2_emulation.so
2020-05-30 12:39:54.527 23257-23315/com.superawesome.metime V/FA: App measurement disabled via the init parameters
2020-05-30 12:39:55.234 23257-23315/com.superawesome.metime I/FA: App measurement initialized, version: 28000
2020-05-30 12:39:55.247 23257-23315/com.superawesome.metime I/FA: To enable debug logging run: adb shell setprop log.tag.FA VERBOSE
2020-05-30 12:39:55.267 23257-23315/com.superawesome.metime I/FA: To enable faster debug mode event logging run:
      adb shell setprop debug.firebase.analytics.app com.superawesome.metime
2020-05-30 12:39:55.274 23257-23315/com.superawesome.metime D/FA: Debug-level message logging enabled
2020-05-30 12:39:57.009 23257-23315/com.superawesome.metime V/FA: Detected application was in foreground
2020-05-30 12:39:57.995 23257-23315/com.superawesome.metime V/FA: Connecting to remote service
2020-05-30 12:40:23.846 23257-23311/com.superawesome.metime W/FirebaseInstanceId: Token retrieval failed: SERVICE_NOT_AVAILABLE. Will retry token retrieval
2020-05-30 12:41:23.931 23257-23311/com.superawesome.metime W/FirebaseInstanceId: Token retrieval failed: SERVICE_NOT_AVAILABLE. Will retry token retrieval
2020-05-30 12:42:54.030 23257-23311/com.superawesome.metime W/FirebaseInstanceId: Token retrieval failed: SERVICE_NOT_AVAILABLE. Will retry token retrieval
```

Comment: The error message is telling you exactly what's going wrong. A null user object means the user isn't fully signed in yet: *java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseUser.getUid()' on a null object reference*

Comment: Hi Doug, I know that it’s there and I’ve tried to fix it based on previous answers from StackOverflow. The problem is there’s only one user. Me. I’ve tried adding listeners to check whether the user was signed in or not, but with no success. It used to work completely fine. 
Do you have a recommendation on how to solve it?

Comment: Not really - you're supposed to use a listener to detect sign-in state.  It seems you're still trying to access the current user without waiting for the listener to become invoked with the user object.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to read through my post.